# What is wrong with this line?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting a

```
Breaking on JScript runtime error - Unknown runtime error
```

on this line:

```
c.innerHTML= '<a name="a1" class="b" href="' + d[2].value + '">' + 
              d[1].value + '</a>';
```

Comment: Can you provide some more context -- the surrounding couple of lines?

Comment: I bet the problem is that "c" is referring to a DOM element (or some sort of thing) for which "innerHTML" doesn't work.

Comment: you are using `innerHTML` that is the first problem, don't do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that `c` is an anchor element and you are trying to set its `innerHTML` to create a child anchor element, which is not valid HTML, though most browsers can tolerate invalid HTML. Something that would make things clearer and help you identify the problem would be to write your code as follows:

```
var b = document.getElementById('Bb1c');
var c = document.createElement('a');
var d = document.forms['f3'].elements;
c.name = 'a1';
c.className = 'b';
c.href = d[2].value;
var value = d[1].value;
// You should really HTML-escape value before assigning it.
c.innerHTML = value;
b.appendChild(c);
```

This will likely still have the same error as before, but it should be easier to figure out on which line the error is occurring. For example, the problem could be that either `d[1]` or `d[2]` is `null`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to escape. Use a combination of single and double quotes.

```
c.innerHTML= '<a name="a1" class="b" href="' + d[2].value + '">' + d[1].value + '</a>';
```

Comment: Well, now I'm not so sure... post up your html as well 
http://jsfiddle.net/nfhY7/

Comment: I wish I could go back and delete this question, by default now I use double and THEN single quotes.  Thanks again.